# Regularexpression that acts like the .NET Mid function

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am making Mainframe socket calls. Each message will have a different response, but contained in that response is a message code which will signify a success or failure.

I have built a socket object which will make the socket call out to the mainframe. I would like to be able to dynamically evaluate the response and have the object determine if it was a success or failure.

**Essentially, I am working with a string response message at this point.**

Ideally, I would save the message "Mid(ResponseMessage,17,2)" as string to then be evaluated. Since I cannot, I am looking at regular expression to do similar functionality.

So, what is the best way to have a regular expression look at a string and have a similar return of the mid expression: Mid(ResponseMessage,17,2)?

Per Ken, I am adding the string value EXAMPLE:"000000000000000099 "

Based on Christians Example, I tried the following code:

`ResponseMessage = "000000000000000099 "` `Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(ResponseMessage,"^.{16}(.{2})").Value`

The output I received was `"000000000000000099"`

The output I would have expected was: `"99"`

Comment: You've provided no sample data that you'll be working with, no information about what you'll be trying to match, no attempts at anything yourself, and no useful information for us. ("I'm working with a string message" and "a regular expression that works like Mid() but I can't use Mid() for some unspecified reason") is no information. If you'd like us to help you, you'll need to [edit] your question to provide much more specific detail about the content and what you're trying to match, as well as show some effort to find a solution yourself.

Comment: Ken, Christian, below, understood. I need to do the same type of function as the Mid function. It doesn't matter what the string value is, it's dynamic.

Comment: Please read the last sentence I wrote in my previous comment. There is **no way** we can help you based on what you have provided. You **must [edit] your question and provide more details if you want help. It's not optional. :-)

Comment: Ok. So you have a string input that consists of 16 digits followed by 2 digits that you want to match? And all inputs consist of 18 digits? If that's not the case, please [edit] your question to provide more detail. I'm really getting tired of having to fight to get you to ask a specific question, when it's **you asking us for help**; you shouldn't make it so da**ed difficult to get information from you when we're doing you the favor.

Comment: Christian was spot on with the solution. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this: `"^.{16}(.{2})"`

**UPDATE**

`Match.Value` is not how you extract a matched group from a regex. You want code like this:

```
private static string Mid172(string text) {
    var match = Regex.Match(text, "^.{16}(.{2})");
    if(match.Success) {
        return match.Groups[1].Value;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Or to make it generic like the VB function it is emulating:

```
private static string Mid(string text, int oneBasedStart, int length) {
    var match = Regex.Match(text, string.Format("^.{{{0}}}(.{{{1}}})", oneBasedStart - 1, length));
    if(match.Success) {
        return match.Groups[1].Value;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, But it's not quite what I'm looking for:<br/>

`ResponseMessage = "000000000000000099         "`
<br/>
`Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(ResponseMessage,"^.{16}(.{2})").Value`
<br/>
`Output results: "000000000000000099"`
<br/>
I would actually be looking for these results: "99"

Comment: @IAmCoder: Why isn't that information being added to your question, as you were asked to do?

Comment: Ken, I appreciate your attempt at helping, but it appears we are off on the concept of what I'm asking for. I'm seeking to get the same functionality with a RegEx as I would with the Mid function as stated in my original post. I need a RegEx to do the same thing as Mid(ResponseMessage,17,2). The string value is dynamic. Make up any string you want for it. I provided an 'example' of data for Christian. The string-data is not in question, the method, however, is.

Comment: @IAmCoder: My regex will do what you ask for. See updated answer.

Comment: Or, to go right back to the beginning - why can't you use Mid, or for that matter Substring?

Comment: Christian, this is perfect! Thank you kindly!